# He "eats vegetables but do not eat meat" because he knows his body and it doesn't digest meat well. - adverbial clause modify the whole thing?

Tags: adverbial-phrases

Lots of sources often say adverbial clauses modify the main verb.

I wonder if adverbial clauses can modify more than two verbs, like in the examples below

Example 1

> He "wears pink in the winter but does not wear pink in the summer" **because for him, pink clothing is winter fashion.**

Example 2

> He "eats vegetables but do not eat meat" **because he knows what is healthy and his body doesn't digest meat well.**

Does the adverbial clause in bold modify the whole thing instead of just the main verb?

Comment: **does** not eat meat

Comment: Is this really an English question? Wouldn't the logic be the same in any language?

Comment: He brushes his teeth after every meal, obeys the speed limit, and pays his taxes on time because he wants to be a model citizen.  I would say that the clause headed by **because** applies (semantically) to the *combined* assertions in the main clause, not to each verb phrase individually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> He "wears pink in the winter but does not wear pink in the summer," **because for him, pink clothing is winter fashion**.

> He "eats vegetables but [does] not eat meat", **because he knows what is healthy and his body doesn't digest meat well**.

Both *wears* and *wear* in #1 are main verbs, and are modified by their adverbial clause.

#2 is similar; both *eats* and *eat* are main verbs, and are modified by their adverbial clause.

To see clearer that *eat* is also a main verb, you can say

> He eats vegetables, but **he** does not eat meat, because he knows what is healthy and his body doesn't digest meat well.